# Powershell invoke-command returns one object property only

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I try to get Windows audit policies on several Windows servers with an Invoke-Command cmdlet. It works fine for all servers, except one where I get only the first object property (the added SecEvtLogMaxSizeKb).
Here is my code:

```
# Get audit policy for computer
$oCompAuditPolicy = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $sCompName -ScriptBlock {
    # Create reporting object for the computer
    $oLocCompAuditPolicy = New-Object PSObject -Property @{}
               
    # Add a property for security event log max size
    $oLocCompAuditPolicy | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "SecEvtLogMaxSizeKb" -Value $(Get-EventLog -List | Where-Object {$_.log -like "Security"}).maximumkilobytes
        
    # Get audit policy on computer and fille the reporting object
    $sCompAuditPolicy = auditPol /get /category:*
    $sCompAuditPolicy | Where-Object { $_ -is [string] -and $_ } <# Remove blank lines #> | Select-Object -Skip 2 <# Headers #> | ForEach-Object {
        # Headers don't have two columns and so don't have two spaces
        if ($_ -like "*  *") {
            # The left and right columns are separated by two spaces, extract into two groups and ignore spaces between them
            $_ -match '  ([a-z, /-]+)  ([a-z, ]+)' | Out-Null

            # Add a property for each audit policy
            $oLocCompAuditPolicy | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "$($Matches[1].Trim())" -Value $Matches[2]
        }
    }

    # Return reporting object
    $oLocCompAuditPolicy
}
```

When I execute the command block directly on the server, I get a full object with all expected properties.

When I compare two servers, both with Windows 2019 OS, the local object returned seem to be the same and they have the same PowerShell version installed:

```
$PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.17763.3770
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.17763.3770
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Any idea to get the full PS object from the Invoke-Command?

Incorrect (i.e. incomplete) output of $oCompAuditPolicy |Format-List *:

```
SecEvtLogMaxSizeKb : 4194240
PSComputerName : xxxxxxxxx
RunspaceId : 4b8dccea-d87f-49c6-a719-21d747a65b5d
PSShowComputerName : True
```

Correct (but I removed some lines) output of $oCompAuditPolicy |Format-List *:

```
SecEvtLogMaxSizeKb : 4194240
Security System Extension : Success and Failure
Credential Validation : Success and Failure
PSComputerName : yyyyyyyyyyy
RunspaceId : 765967e6-8735-45e1-bc38-922f343a7f12
PSShowComputerName : True
```

Comment: How are you assessing the output? What happens if you do: `$oCompAuditPolicy |Format-List * -Format` on the client side after `Invoke-Command` returns?

Comment: I've just noticed the returned objects are not presented the same way (but they are both PSCustomObject).
Incorrect output of $oCompAuditPolicy |Format-List *:
Correct output of $oCompAuditPolicy |Format-List *:

Comment: You're gonna have to be more descriptive than "not presented the same way" - no one else can see your screen :)

Comment: Please [add those details to your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76572763/edit)

Comment: Why not do `$sCompAuditPolicy = auditPol /get /category:* /r | ConvertFrom-Csv` to get all data as structured **objects** instead of trying to manually parse the textual representation? [\r](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/auditpol-get) Displays the output in report format, comma-separated value (CSV)

Comment: With `$sCompAuditPolicy = auditPol /get /category:* /r | ConvertFrom-Csv` it returns nothing from the erroneous server.

Comment: I changed the Invoke-Command to use the -Session option instead of -ComputerName. At first, it seemed it worked. But when I want to export the returned result with `$oCompAuditPolicy | Export-Csv -Path my_csv_file` I get this error: `Export-Csv : Cannot append CSV content to the following file: my_csv_file. The appended object does not have a property that corresponds to the following column:
Security System Extension. To continue with mismatched properties, add the -Force parameter, and then retry the command.`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I slightly changed my code. Here it is, with the foreach loop to get the audit policies from several computers:

```
foreach ($sCompName in $aCompNames){
    # Create PS session
    $oSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $sCompName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    # Get audit policy for computer if session is valid
    if ($oSession) {
        $oCompAuditPolicy = Invoke-Command -Session $oSession -ScriptBlock {
            # Create reporting object for the computer
            $oLocCompAuditPolicy = [pscustomobject]@{
                SecEvtLogMaxSizeKb = $(Get-EventLog -List | Where-Object {$_.log -like "Security"}).maximumkilobytes
            }
                    
            # Get audit policy on computer and fille the reporting object
            $sCompAuditPolicy = auditPol /get /category:*
            $sCompAuditPolicy | Where-Object { $_ -is [string] -and $_ } <# Remove blank lines #> | Select-Object -Skip 2 <# Headers #> | ForEach-Object {
                # Headers don't have two columns and so don't have two spaces
                if ($_ -like "*  *") {
                    # The left and right columns are separated by two spaces, extract into two groups and ignore spaces between them
                    $_ -match '  ([a-z, /-]+)  ([a-z, ]+)' | Out-Null
    
                    # Add a property for each audit policy
                    $oLocCompAuditPolicy | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "$($Matches[1].Trim())" -Value $Matches[2]
                }
            }

            # Return reporting object
            $oLocCompAuditPolicy

        } -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

        # Add a 'Group Membership' property as necessary (relevant for Win 2016 computers only)
        if (-Not $oCompAuditPolicy.PSObject.Properties["Group Membership"]) {
            $oCompAuditPolicy | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Group Membership" -Value "-"
        }
        
        # Add a property related to type of computer (DC or not)
        if ($aDCs -contains $sCompName) {
            $sCompType = "DC"
        } else {
            $sCompType = "Standard"
        }
        $oCompAuditPolicy | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Type" -Value $sCompType
        Write-Host $sCompName
        $oCompAuditPolicy | Export-Csv -Path AudPol.csv -Append
        $aAuditPolicies += $oCompAuditPolicy
        $oSession | Remove-PSSession
    }
}
```

And I now notice something really strange: if I run the block after 'if ($oSession)' with an existing session, it works. But if I run the code starting from the session creation, it fails.

---

OK, it seems the PSSession is not immediately ready to use fully. If I wait 4-5 seconds, it works.

---

I got it! It seems that the 'auditpol' command needs some time to return something once the session is created. Thus, I created a short loop to wait for it.